# Trying to do an error message of missing required permission for discord bot on python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making an discord bot on python, and I don't wanna that regular users used the moderation commands. I know how to do a check for permissions,
`@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)`, but I don't know how to do an error message of missing required permissions.
I tried that:

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(':redTick: You don\'t have permission to kick members.')
```

*I found that on Stack Overflow*

But in the cmd it says that:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: kick_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'`

And if I swapped 'ctx' and 'error', like `async def kick_error(self, error, ctx):`, it says the same thing, only instead of `missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'` he wrote `missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`

How can I fix it? And is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the error is instance of `commands.MissingRequiredArgument`

Seeing the error I assume that you are not in a cog, so remove `self`

```py
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(':redTick: You don\'t have permission to kick members.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Missing Argument")
    else: raise(error) # for other errors so they dont get suppressed
```

Comment: It only worked when I gave no arguments, when I as @everyone tried to kick someone, it prints in to console that I don't have permissions, he didn't say it in Discord.

Comment: check `if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):`

Comment: replace `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):` on `if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):`, right? If yes, that still not working